# Subtracting each image in two image collections in Google Earh Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, band

I have two image collections with 14 images each. I need to subtract the first image of the first collection to the first image of the second collection, the second image of the first collection to the second image of the second collection and so on, until the last image. My aim is to create a new image collection which contains the result of this subtraction.
With `zip` I get a list of two elements list.

```
var coll = coll_GEE.toList(14).zip(coll_SNAP.toList(14))
```

Is it possible to apply a function like this to every sublist of the list, avoiding a for cycle?

```
var subtract = function (list){
     var GEE = ee.Image(list.get(0))
     var SNAP = ee.Image (list.get(1))
     var subt = SNAP.subtract(GEE)
     return subt};
```

I read the `list.map(baseAlgorithm, dropNulls)` can only return a object.

Comment: In your case I think I'd try to combine() the two image collections and then map a function to return the difference of each image; return im.select(0).subtract(im.select(1)).